# Ansible regex_replace filter does not work

Tags: regex, ansible

I try to use Ansible regex_replace to filter the sub-string "application_1514971620021_4505" from a status message.
In the shell the message looks like this:
 [image]

I run this code in Ansible:

```
---
- hosts: [npif]
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - block:

      - name: Admin submit check
        command: chdir=/usr/spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE-yarn/ bin/xd-yarn submitted
        register: admininfo

      - debug: msg="{{ admininfo.stdout }}"

      - debug: msg="{{ admininfo.stdout | regex_replace('^.*(application\_\d.*\_\d*)\s.*', '\\1') }}"

      become: yes
      become_user: ingestdev
```

debug: msg="{{ admininfo.stdout }}" returns the status message in the different format than in the shell:

```
ok: [npif] => {
    "msg": "  APPLICATION ID                  USER       NAME       QUEUE     TYPE  STARTTIME       FINISHTIME  STATE    FINALSTATUS  ORIGINAL TRACKING URL\n  ------------------------------  ---------  ---------  --------  ----  --------------  ----------  -------  -----------  ------------------------\n  application_1514971620021_4505  ingestdev  spring-xd  batch_cb  XD    1/3/18 2:49 PM  N/A         RUNNING  UNDEFINED    http://x.x.x.x:9394"
}
```

When I run the second debug with regex_replace, I get the identical output to the first debug output - no regex_replace filter has been applied. The regex filter is correct - I've tested it externally. Basically the Ansible code is working too - I have tested with line below and got "test" as expected.

```
- debug: msg="{{ 'test.home.com' | regex_replace('^([^.]*).*', '\\1') }}"
```

Do you have an idea, what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: What string is this `^([^.]*).*` acting on ? If there is no `.` it will delete the line. If there is always a  `.` , it's better to use this `\..*` replace with nothing.

Comment: The string you have mentioned was for test only - to see, that regex_replace work. My issue with the regex expression in the main code: regex_replace('^.*(application\_\d.*\_\d*)\s.*' - it is correct but does not apply in Ansible

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: It is well described in the question.

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Just post the text itself. That makes it easier to read, easier to search, and easier to copy-and-paste if someone wanted to test things out while working on an answer.

Comment: You could click on the pic and get the larger view. For me was important to show the original output layout, which could change on copy-paste. So the screenshot was necessary in this particular case.

Comment: Posting the text would preserve the original layout. Try not to intentionally make life difficult for the people you're asking to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your remark. I will take it in account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that `.*` doesn't appear to match newlines.  Consider this:

```
- debug:                                                                    
    msg: "{{ admininfo.stdout | regex_replace('.*application', 'foo') }}"
```

This will replace `application` with `foo`, but will leave the header lines intact.  Since the `^` anchors your regular expression to the beginning of the *text* (not the beginning of a *line*) your expression will never match.

You can take advantage of the fact that ansible has already provided you with individual lines in the `stdout_lines` key of your registered output.  In this case, you would use something like:

```
- debug:
    msg: >
      {{ admininfo.stdout_lines[2] | regex_replace('^.*(application_\d.*_\d*)\s.*', '\1') }}
```

Note here that I've made a few changes in how things are quoted and escaped.  In particular, I'm using the folded literal operator `>` in place of double quotes, and you neede to use `\1` instead of `\\1` for your replacement string.

This gives me:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "application_1514971620021_4505\n"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer.  I edited my code as you had suggested AND IT WORKS !!! : - debug: msg="{{ admininfo.stdout_lines[2] | regex_replace('^.*(application\_\d.*\_\d*)\s.*', '\1') }}"